# Adding SMTP to the php form Bootstrap

Tags: php, forms, smtp

I have this form on my site:

```
https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-recaptcha
```

I want to add SMTP thanks to this:

```
https://www.lifewire.com/send-email-from-php-script-using-smtp-authentication-and-ssl-1171197
```

How to add this to the file contact.php (below) ?. He works independently. I need the form from Bootstrap to send emails via SMTP.
The smtp connection is correct. Only I can not deal with sending all data from the form in this way. This is done using the normal php mail function.

```
require_once "Mail.php";
$from = "Sandra Sender <mail@mail>";
$to = "Ramona Recipient <mail@mail>";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
$host = "host";
$username = "mail";
$password = "haslo";
$headers = array ('From' => $from,
  'To' => $to,
  'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
```

contact.php

```
<?php
// require ReCaptcha class
require('recaptcha-master/src/autoload.php');

// configure
// an email address that will be in the From field of the email.
$from = 'Demo contact form <--->';

// an email address that will receive the email with the output of the form
$sendTo = 'Demo contact form <--->';

// subject of the email
$subject = 'New message from contact form';

// form field names and their translations.
// array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message', 'name2' => 'Name2', 'surname2' => 'Surname2', 'selekt' => 'Wybrane');

$selectOption = $_POST['selekt'];

// message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';

// If something goes wrong, we will display this message.
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

// ReCaptch Secret
$recaptchaSecret = '---';

// let's do the sending

// if you are not debugging and don't need error reporting, turn this off by error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try {
    if (!empty($_POST)) {

        // validate the ReCaptcha, if something is wrong, we throw an Exception,
        // i.e. code stops executing and goes to catch() block

        if (!isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
            throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha is not set.');
        }

        // do not forget to enter your secret key from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin

        $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($recaptchaSecret, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost());

        // we validate the ReCaptcha field together with the user's IP address

        $response = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        if (!$response->isSuccess()) {
            throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha was not validated.');
        }

        // everything went well, we can compose the message, as usually

        $emailText = "You have a new message from your contact form\n=============================\n";

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email
            if (isset($fields[$key])) {
                $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
            }
        }

        // All the neccessary headers for the email.
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
            'From: ' . $from,
            'Reply-To: ' . $from,
            'Return-Path: ' . $from,
        );

        // Send email
        mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

        $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $e->getMessage());
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
} else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

Log errors:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Mail' not found in /home/lukaste/domains/lukaste.vdl.pl/public_html/luw2/contact.php:88, referer: http://lukaste.vdl.pl/luw2/
>       mod_fcgid: stderr: Stack trace:, referer: http://lukaste.vdl.pl/luw2/
>       mod_fcgid: stderr: #0 {main}, referer: http://lukaste.vdl.pl/luw2/
>       mod_fcgid: stderr:   thrown in /home/lukaste/domains/lukaste.vdl.pl/public_html/luw2/contact.php on line 88, referer: http://lukaste.vdl.pl/luw2/
>       File does not exist: /home/lukaste/domains/lukaste.vdl.pl/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://lukaste.vdl.pl/luw2/

Line 88:

```
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
```

All send mail:

```
// Send email
require_once "Mail.php";
$from = "Sandra Sender <kontakt@graftet.pl>";
$to = "Ramona Recipient <lukaste90@gmail.com>";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
$host = "s12.linuxpl.com";
$username = "kontakt@graftet.pl";
$password = "eRsPdWgB";
$headers = array ('From' => $from,
  'To' => $to,
  'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
 } else {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
 }

        $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $e->getMessage());
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
} else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

/ edit, contact.php with phpmailer. No errors in the logs. The form does not send.

```
<?php
// require ReCaptcha class
require('recaptcha-master/src/autoload.php');

// configure
// an email address that will be in the From field of the email.
$from = 'Demo contact form <lukaste90@gmail.com>';

// an email address that will receive the email with the output of the form
$sendTo = 'Demo contact form <lukaste90@gmail.com>';

// subject of the email
$subject = 'Wiadomość z formularz wps.lublin.uw.gov.pl';

// form field names and their translations.
// array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$fields = array('name' => 'Imię', 'surname' => 'Nazwisko', 'phone' => 'Telefon', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Wiadomość', 'pesel' => 'PESEL', 'sprawa' => 'Numer sprawy', 'rodzaj' => 'Rodzaj zapytania', 'dotyczy' => 'Dotyczy');


// message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';

// If something goes wrong, we will display this message.
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

// ReCaptch Secret
$recaptchaSecret = '6LcqdV4UAAAAAOWvJblsdZuxVTHJr3-uDCXutqxM';

// let's do the sending

// if you are not debugging and don't need error reporting, turn this off by error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try {
    if (!empty($_POST)) {

        // validate the ReCaptcha, if something is wrong, we throw an Exception,
        // i.e. code stops executing and goes to catch() block

        if (!isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
            throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha is not set.');
        }

        // do not forget to enter your secret key from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin

        $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($recaptchaSecret, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost());

        // we validate the ReCaptcha field together with the user's IP address

        $response = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        if (!$response->isSuccess()) {
            throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha was not validated.');
        }

        // everything went well, we can compose the message, as usually

        $emailText = "You have a new message from your contact form\n=============================\n";

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email
            if (isset($fields[$key])) {
                $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
            }
        }

        // All the neccessary headers for the email.
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
            'From: ' . $from,
            'Reply-To: ' . $from,
            'Return-Path: ' . $from,
        );



        // Send email


        //error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_STRICT);

date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "serwer"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "serwer"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "@"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "pass";        // SMTP account password

$mail->SetFrom('mail', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("mail","First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "Wiadomosc";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "mail";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}

        $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $e->getMessage());
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
} else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

Comment: _"Only I can not deal with sending all data from the form in this way"_ - What do you mean? What data? In what way? Why would the form need be any different from what you already have?

Comment: Right. It has to be the same only with smtp.
Data from the form that is downloaded is:
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message', 'name2' => 'Name2', 'surname2' => 'Surname2', 'selekt' => 'Wybrane');

Comment: So have you tried implementing the other mail script? If yes, please explain what issues you have. If no, try and implement it. I don't really see what the question or the issue is. Just replace the code that sends the mail.

Comment: Instead of this line?
mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

I tried different and I have different errors in the logs.

Comment: Yes. Just change all the code that's relevant to `mail()` (including the headers) and use the code from the other script. If you run into some errors, you need to show us what you've tried and what those errors are, or we won't be able to know how to help.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question, I added errors after editing the code.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you have installed the mail package correctly or that you don't have the PEAR folder setup in your php.ini. However, using PEAR and install things globally is not really a good practice anymore. I would recommend that you use something like PHPMailer or SwiftMailer instead. Then you can either download those packages and put them into your application or use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) to add it as a dependency. That will make your application more portable.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I added phpmailer. No errors in the logs, and the form still does not send. He does not react. I edited the question, I added the whole contact.php code.

On different ftp servers, the same error in Console (Chrome):
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)